# Best Strategy to implement TimeZone in an existing SpringBoot REST application

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-boot, timezone

Any best strategy to implement TimeZone for an existing application.

because, there will be many places using updatedBy, createdBy etc..Any good

design pattern to make it easy to implement

Answer (score 3):

Store UTC time, provide UTC time, let client convert it to whatever time zone they deem fit (if that is a browser for example, they can use the browsers timezone).

Comment: So the UTC time has to be passed for all requests ?

Comment: Not necessarily, they can pass the time with a valid time zone (I suggest standardizing on iso 8601), as long as you store it in UTC (you'll have to convert it of course) and return it as UTC.

Comment: And for "time zone", use a real [time zone name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in form of "continent/region" such as `America/Montreal`, **never the 3-4 letter abbreviations** like `IST`, `EST`, etc.